# Не работает сохранение байтов в файл

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сохранить байты в файл

```
 String papkablia = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/W1/1.txt";
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(papkablia);
 String s = "аапопглрдшощжодшнгокнрло";
 fos.write(s.getBytes());
 fos.close();
```

..и ничего не происходит, ошибок нет. В чем может быть проблема, может кто то знает рабочий способ?

Comment: Выполните fos.flush(); перед закрытием

Comment: Не помогло, файл 1.txt все так же пуст